# R - mutate columns loops over mutated columns when specifying multiple columns to add

Tags: r, dplyr

following my [recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73093280/modular-filter-and-mutate-based-on-user-input-r/73093301?noredirect=1#comment129094660_73093301) I am stuck with a mutation that mutates across recently mutated columns.

```r
sheet <- sheet %>%
        group_by(across(all_of(.GlobalEnv$filter_list[[select_filter]]))) %>%
        mutate(
          across(where(is.numeric), ~ (sum(.x)) , .names="{.col}_sum"), 
          across(where(is.numeric), ~ (mean(.x)) , .names="{.col}_average"), 
          across(where(is.numeric), ~ (sd(.x)) , .names="{.col}_SD") 
          #total = sum(.data[[names(sheet[,10])]], na.rm = TRUE)
          )
```

is calling all numeric columns and performs a function on new column. Problem is I for a column calculated fo `sum` I get `colname_sum` and `colname_sum_average` and `colname_sum_average_SD`. How can I avoid this duplicity?

[image]

Thanks to @julian answer, I can manage this by:

```r
sheet <- sheet %>%
        group_by(across(all_of(.GlobalEnv$filter_list[[select_filter]]))) %>%
        summarise(
          across(
            where(is.numeric),
            list(sum = sum, average = mean, sd = sd),
            .names = "{.col}_{.fn}"
          )
          )
```

Although this brings out another problem, where if I define my own function, the data is calculated on each value instead of by grouping:

```r
testfunc <- function(.) {
  . + 1000
}
sheet <- sheet %>%
        group_by(across(all_of(.GlobalEnv$filter_list[[select_filter]]))) %>%
        summarise(
          across(
            where(is.numeric),
            list(sum = sum, average = mean, sd = sd, test = testfunc),
            .names = "{.col}_{.fn}"
          #total = sum(.data[[names(sheet[,10])]], na.rm = TRUE)
          )
          )
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `list` of functions inside the `mutate`

```r
sheet <- sheet %>%
  group_by(across(all_of(.GlobalEnv$filter_list[[select_filter]]))) %>%
  mutate(
    across(where(is.numeric), list(sum = sum, average = mean, sd = sd) , .names="{.col}_{.fn}")
  )
```

But it's better to use `summarise` instead of `mutate`

```r
sheet <- sheet %>%
  group_by(across(all_of(.GlobalEnv$filter_list[[select_filter]]))) %>%
  summarise(
    across(where(is.numeric), list(sum = sum, average = mean, sd = sd) , .names="{.col}_{.fn}")
  )
```

Example with the`iris` dataset

```r
iris %>%
  mutate(
    across(where(is.numeric), list(sum = sum, average = mean, sd = sd) , .names="{.col}_{.fn}"))
```

Comment: Amazing, that's so much cleaner! Thank you very much! I know I am not supposed to thank on comments, but can't help it :P

Comment: One problem that arises with this method though - when I try to add my own function to the list, it does not keep the grouping:

```r
testfunc <- function(.x) {
  .x + 1000
}
sheet <- sheet %>%
        group_by(across(all_of(.GlobalEnv$filter_list[[select_filter]]))) %>%
        mutate(
          across(
            where(is.numeric),
            list(sum = sum, average = mean, sd = sd, test = testfunc),
            .names = "{.col}_{.fn}"
          #total = sum(.data[[names(sheet[,10])]], na.rm = TRUE)
          )
          )
```

Comment: editing question to add the current state

Comment: Can you paste the output of `dput(sheet)` here ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246905/discussion-between-julien-and-tiriyon).